# Accessing javascript documentation from html code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, documentation

I'm working on a html project and I wanted to create the documentation for some JavaScript libraries that we often use.

The structure of the project is the following:

- Project

  - function.js
  - index.html

The function I want to access the documentation for is in the *function.js* file and is as follows:

```
/**
* This the function which documentation I want to access
* @param param1- First parameter 
* @param param2 - Second parameter
* @returns something when function complete
*/
function updateChecklist(param1,param2){
// do stuff
}
```

Is there any way to configure the index.html file so that I can access this documentation the following way:

[Accessing prepend documentation from html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItANh.png)

The editor I'm using is VScode and the project doesn't use any JavaScript framework.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking exactly and add a code example. What does `I have generated the documentation and it is accessible from any javascript file` mean? I don't understand the first or the second part of that statement

Comment: Thank for your comment @ChrisG, I have edited the question, hope now makes more sense.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing JS code inside a <script> tag and you want the help window pop up in VS code? Try moving the code into a separate script.js file and incude that in your HTML below functions.js. Writing a pure JS file is more likely to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ChrisG, I have studied that approach and it works but my question is if is there any form of doing the same but from the html code.

Comment: Don't know, don't think so.